# Closed and unbounded set on a specific set or ordinals.

Tags: set-theory

I'm having problems on showing the following:

Let $\kappa$ be a strongly inaccesible cardinal. Show that the set of all ordinals $\alpha <\kappa$ such that $V_\alpha \models ZFC$ contains a club.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to show that the set of $\alpha < \kappa$ for which $V_{\alpha}$ is an elementary substructure of $V_{\kappa}$ forms a club. You can show this by considering looking at closure points of Skolems functions.

Comment: Thanks. Although, I'm looking for a "combinatorial" proof.

Comment: It is a Lowenheim-Skolem type argument. I don't see how you can get around it.

Comment: I'd argue that Lowenheim-Skolem arguments *are* combinatorial, but that's a personal opinion.

Answer (score 3):

We show that
$$
C := \{\alpha < \kappa \mid V_\alpha \prec V_\kappa \}
$$
is a club. As $V_\kappa$ is a model of ZFC, this proves the initial claim.

Note, that $C$ is closed (this follows from the Tarski-Vaught test).

To see that $C$ is unbounded, proceed as follows: Given $\alpha_0 < \kappa$, recursively construct a sequence $(\alpha_n \mid n \le \omega)$ as follows:

$\alpha_{n+1}$ is the least $\alpha < \kappa$ s.t. $V_{\alpha_n} \cup \{ \alpha_n \} \subseteq V_{\alpha}$ and s.t. for every formula of the form $\exists v_0 \phi(v_0,y_1, \ldots, v_n)$ and $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in V_{\alpha_n}$: If there is some $x_0 \in V_{\kappa}$ with 
$$V_{\kappa} \models \phi(x_0,x_1, \ldots, x_n),$$
then there already is some $x'_0 \in V_{\alpha}$ with
$$V_{\kappa} \models \phi(x'_0,x_1, \ldots, x_n).$$

Now $\alpha_\omega := \sup \{ \alpha_n \mid n < \omega \}$ satisfies
$$
V_{\alpha_\omega} \prec V_{\kappa}
$$
(again by the Tarski-Vaught test and the fact that $(\alpha_n \mid n < \omega)$ is strictly increasing).